# VBA add-ins load but do not work in Office 2010

Tags: vba, add-in, office-2010

I've created several add-ins for PowerPoint 2010 and Excel 2010 using VBA (I don't have Visual Studio available). The add-ins work fine on thin clients using Windows 7 Enterprise SP1 32-bit and Office Professional Plus 2010 14.0.6123.5001 32-bit. On thick clients (regular PCs) with Windows 7 and Office 2010 32-bit, the add-ins will not work. Nothing happens when users try to install them; the toolbars do not appear, but there are no error messages or notification bars. The add-ins display as loaded in the add-in manager, though, and it's possible to run macros manually from the VBA editor.

I've investigated issues with security settings and digital signatures. The add-ins are digitally signed, although the add-in manager does not display the publisher information. Users are prompted to trust the publisher when attempting to install the add-ins; trusting the publisher does not make the add-ins work and does not lead to any error messages.

In the add-ins tab of the trust center, the option to "Disable notification for unsigned add-ins" is checked and grayed out on the thick clients where the add-ins do not work, and unchecked on the thin clients where they do work. When checked on the thin clients, the add-ins continue to work, so I don't think this is the problem. And both deployments use the 32-bit version of office, so it's probably not that either.

Any ideas what might be causing the problem, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem, and the instructions for trusting publishers recorded on this website helped me to resolve the problem:
http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?199-Security-In-Microsoft-Office
However, for mine to work I could not use the certificate created using the selfcert.exe program that comes with Microsoft Office.